# Streaming query results with mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express

I've been trying to use the `mssql` package on npm to connect to a SQL Server and stream back the query results. The problem is with streaming. I tried to follow the API doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#streaming like this:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const sql     = require('mssql');
const sts     = require('string-to-stream');

let connectStr1 = "***";
let queryStr = "***";
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(connectStr1)
    .then(() => {
        let request = new sql.Request();
        request.stream = true;
        request.query(queryStr);
        request
        .on('row', (row) => {
            sts(row).pipe(res);
        }).on('error', (err) => {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
        }).on('finish', () => {
            res.end();
        });


    }).catch((err) => {
         res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
});
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Listening to port 4000'));
```

The error reads

> possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 finish listeners added.

Following this I tried

```
request.setMaxListener(Infinity)
```

but the error was still there.

My question is why there were so many listeners created? And how to stream back the results in the correct way? Thanks in advance!